# R.string.something - не строка?

Tags: java, android

Создал класс `ItemMain`. Его конструктор принимает `String'овую` переменную
Добавляю в ListView экземпляр класса:

```
lists.add(new ItemMain(R.string.Home));
```

Появляется ошибка, что `R.string.Home` - целый тип.
Подскажите, как можно сделать по-другому?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`R.string.Home` это действительно число-идентификатор к-л ресурса проекта.

Для его преобразования в строку есть метод `getString()` в классах `Context`, `Fragment`, etc.

Т.е., находясь в активити/фрагменте/сервисе надо писать так:

```
String stringFromRes = getString(R.string.Home);
```

---

ресурсы лучше не называть с большой буквы и вообще большие буквы там не использовать

Comment: А на что это повлияет?

Comment: Может и не повлиять, но лучше не пробовать и писать только строчными плюс подчеркивания